# systemd: How do I automount a USB filesystem using /etc/fstab?

Tags: systemd, autofs, automounting

I want my USB filesystems to automount when I connect the device.

How do I setup automount with `systemd` via `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Connect your device and find out the UUID of the filesystem by running either `blkid` or `lsblk -f`.

Add a line to `/etc/fstab` such as:

```
UUID=05C5-A73A  /mnt/32GBkey  vfat  noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=2,x-systemd.device-timeout=2
```

Then execute:

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart local-fs.target
```

Explanation:

- `noauto` - don't mount with `mount -a`
- `nofail` - boot will continue even if this mount point is not mounted successfully
- `x-systemd.automount` tell `systemd` to automount this etnry
- `x-systemd.idle-timeout=2` - wait 2 seconds before unmounting the device after last usage
- `x-systemd.device-timeout=2` - wait only 2 seconds before giving `No such device` if the device is not connected

Note:

1. There are no quotes around the `UUID` number.
2. The mount point directory doesn't need to exist - it will be created

For more information about the options available, see [systemd.mount(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html)

Comment: Is there any advantage to this over a `udev` rule? This seems very specific for a single device (given the `UUID`-dependency of `fstab`), where a `udev` rule could cover e.g. any USB flash drive.

Comment: `/etc/fstab` doesn't have the dependency you assert, accepting `LABEL=...`, `PARTLABEL=...` and good old `/dev/usbkey`. You could always setup a `udev` rule to make `/dev/usbkey`, but I don't know how to mount using `udev` alone.

Comment: Update 2019: I tested this solution successfully on Debian 9.9 and found that it works fine. Note that since this is an automount, `df` might not show the filesystem as mounted.

Comment: while this may work, why go through the trouble? if you do just as you have shown above in fstab but for options you specify (perhaps in addition to other useful ones) `nofail` (noting that you _do not_ use `noauto`) then the USB will be mounted at boot if it is plugged in. And, in fact, will be mounted any some point in the future if the USB device were to be plugged in at some later time. No need to involve systemd as directly as shown.

Comment: With this config, how to prepare device for ejecting?